# Streaming Int issue

Tags: java

i am really confused about some thing, and as i searched every thing is ok in my coding !
here when i use this code

```
 sOutput.writeObject(theuser);
        sOutput.writeObject(thepass);
        sOutput.writeObject(thename);
        sOutput.writeObject(themail);
        sOutput.writeObject(thephone);
```

and recieve with this

```
String theuser = (String) sInput.readObject();
            display(theuser);
            String thepass = (String) sInput.readObject();
            display(thepass);
            String thename = (String) sInput.readObject();
            display(thename);
            String themail = (String) sInput.readObject();
            display(themail);
            String thephone = (String) sInput.readObject();
            display(thephone);
```

everything works fine, but when i add these to the ready and write

```
int RID = (int) sInput.readInt();
```

to the read and

```
 sOutput.writeInt(RID);
```

to the write

then it throws no exception, no error, just my server stops there at reading it ! RID is defined Int in sender ,its been given a random number. can you please help me?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your error

Comment: got fixed down there dude, thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the reading program is stuck waiting for the input, and you know for sure that the writing program writes the data to its output, it is often the case that this happens because the written data has been buffered. In other words, it's been placed in a holding location on the sender, and not put on the wire to be sent to the receiver.

A simple way to fix this is to call `flush()` after writing the last element of data, like this:

```
sOutput.writeInt(RID);
sOutput.flush();
```

Comment: aaand i also used    String newRID = Integer.toString(RID);   to turn it into string + your tip and it worked thank you very much